# problems with scrollview (android-studio)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-xml, android-scrollview

My problem is that I duplicate the contents of the layout and I do not understand the reason.
I'm working with fragments and the code is as follows

fragment code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_crear_itinerario"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:name="com.example.pablo.p_final2.CrearItinerarioFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

java fragment

```
public class CrearItinerarioFragment extends Fragment{

    private Button continuar;
    private EditText pob, nomb;
    private int flag1 = 0,flag2 = 0;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_crear_itinerario, container, false);


        pob = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.Poblacion);
        nomb = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.Nombre);

        continuar = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.BotonContinuar);

        pob.addTextChangedListener(new TextValidator(pob) {
            @Override
            public void validate(EditText editText, String text) {
                //Implementamos la validación De campo vacio
                if( text.length() <= 0  ) {
                    pob.setError(getString(R.string.CampoVacio));
                    flag1 = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    flag1 = 1;
                }
            }
        });

        nomb.addTextChangedListener(new TextValidator(nomb) {
            @Override
            public void validate(EditText editText, String text) {
                //Implementamos la validación de campo vacio
                if( text.length() <= 0  ) {
                    nomb.setError(getString(R.string.CampoVacio));
                    flag2 = 0;
                }else
                {
                    flag2 = 1;
                }
            }
        });

        continuar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(flag1!=1 || flag2 !=1)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(CrearItinerarioFragment.this.getActivity(), getString(R.string.CamposVacios),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(CrearItinerarioFragment.this.getActivity(), getString(R.string.ItinerarioCreado), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //Creamos el intent
                    Intent intent = new Intent(CrearItinerarioFragment.this.getActivity(), ControlarItinerarioActivity.class);

                    //Iniciamos la nueva actividad
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

            }
        });

    return view;
    }
}
```

scrollview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_hacer_foto">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/LblTitulo"
            android:text="@string/TituloFoto"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Titulo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:maxLength="30" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/LblComentario"
            android:text="@string/ComentarioFoto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Comentario"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:maxLength="400"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/BtnContinuar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:text="@string/continuar"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

![1]: http://en.zimagez.com/zimage/photo1278635382500599725.php "correct"

![2]: http://en.zimagez.com/zimage/photo1278635382500599724.php "problem"

I want it to stay the same as in the first photo, but as soon as I click on one of the edittext or move the screen is set as the second

Thank you very much

Comment: Add you fragment code

Comment: Java code for fragment

Comment: Post the code for the activity where you're creating CrearItinerarioFragment.

Answer (score 0):

if you are adding data in layout dynamically, then you need to remove all views and add them again

Can you please show code what you are doing in Fragment class where you adding views in framlayout